# How to use a Regex to remove a word only when it occurs at the end of a string (for Yahoo Pipes)?

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I need a Regex that will look at the last word in the string and eliminate it if it's a word that I've selected. For instance, if I'm selecting the word "dog," "This dog is a great dog" would return "This dog is a great." I don't want it to affect all the instances of that word, only if it happens to be at the very end of a string.

This is for a [Yahoo Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/cantvchicago/ce3c90d70b1460ed17aff10c8a766e69) that I'm setting up. Thanks in advance for your help.
-Mike

Comment: I think you could do with tidying up the question a little and identifying the requirements better. You first ask about selecting the word "dog," with a comma. The next sentence "This dog is a great dog" ends with "dog" but then you add a full stop in "This dog is a great."

Comment: @rrrr: That's the way you learn punctuation in American English - if a partial sentence ends in a quote, the punctuation character is pulled inside the quote. [Of course, this is extremely confusing for programmers](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/writing-style.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex `\bdog$` matches only at the end of the string. If there can be whitespace after your keyword, try `\bdog\s*$`. If you want to allow other characters (except for alphanumerics) after `dog`, for example punctuation, then use `\bdog\W*$`.

`\b` is a word boundary anchor that makes sure that only an entire word `dog` is matched - not part of a word as in `underdog`.

`\s` matches whitespace.

`\w` matches an alphanumeric characters; `\W` matches anything that's *not* an alnum.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\s?dog[\s\.]*$/
```

- 1 optional whitespace
- `dog`
- 0 or more: whitespace or `.`
- End of line

Comment: This will also match "This dog is a great dog. . . . . . "

Comment: Right, and the point was to remove the final word and end the sentence with a single period. Sometimes you have to read into the missing specs in the OPs question to estimate the best answer.

Comment: I think he didn't want to match repeating periods. Probably he wants something like /\s?dog\s*\.?$/